# Web Scraping To Form A Database of News

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am creating a web scraper for different news outlets. I trying to create one for `The Hindu` newspaper.

I want to get the news from the various links mentioned in its archives. Lets say I want to get the news at the links mentioned on the following day : `http://www.thehindu.com/archive/web/2010/06/19/` that is 19june, 2010.

Right now I have written the following lines of code  :

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.thehindu.com/archive/web/2010/06/19/"

br =  mechanize.Browser()
htmltext = br.open(url).read()

articletext = ""
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
for tag in soup.findAll('li', attrs={"data-section":"Business"}):
    articletext += tag.contents[0]
print articletext
```

But I am unable to get the required results. I am basically stuck. Can someone help me to sort it out?

Comment: Dont add both the `python-2.7` and `python-3.x` tags to your question, that just confuses people what version of Python you're using.

Comment: if you are new to Python probably a web crawler is not the best "hello world" to get aquainted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.thehindu.com/archive/web/2010/06/19/"

br =  mechanize.Browser()
htmltext = br.open(url).read()

articletext = ""
for tag_li in soup.findAll('li', attrs={"data-section":"Op-Ed"}):
    for link in tag_li.findAll('a'):
        urlnew = urlnew = link.get('href')
        brnew =  mechanize.Browser()
        htmltextnew = brnew.open(urlnew).read()            
        articletext = ""
        soupnew = BeautifulSoup(htmltextnew)
        for tag in soupnew.findAll('p'):
            articletext += tag.text
        print re.sub('\s+', ' ', articletext, flags=re.M)

driver.close()
```

For `re` you might have to import the `re` module.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you check out [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org).  Try their tutorial with your parameters and experiment with that.  They have a much more developed web crawling infrastructure than the mechanize module.

Comment: Sir, I am already new to Python Programming. With Scrapy, I am feeling a little more uncomfortable. Thanks

Comment: Given that you are new to Python, if you insist in "learn" writing a web crawler you should listen to this answer and learn Scrapy, since you are new the effort will be almost the same, but the result is way different.

Comment: Scrapy is actually pretty simple, it borrows a number of things from the django project in setting up a spidering/web crawling project.  At first it seems fairly intimidating, but give it some time, work thru the tutorials, and try to apply that knowledge to what you are trying to accomplish.